# Repeatable background icons with animations

Tags: html, css, animation, background-image, absolute

Take a look at the image to start. The idea is that the green/red stars are supposed to be randomly placed in the background of a row, with content around it. We'd like them to animate, etc...

[image]

To add some flare, we would like it to animate, which is really no big deal. There are a few schools of thought. On one hand, you can use the background-image property, and since you can have multiple backgrounds, it should just be handled and you could position them. On another hand, you could code an image onto the page itself, and position it absolutely. Here's where it gets tricky. What if I don't want to have 10 background-images? What if I don't want to put a span 10 times on my page?

Is there a cleaner, more efficient way to do this??

I'll include a codepen where I laid it out using the span idea, but I'm really hoping there is a much more professional way then injecting 10 span tags or background-images onto the page/stylesheet.

Here is the codepen.

`https://codepen.io/juandahveed/pen/XoMeLo`

you can see the dilema;

**:: it's either ::**

```
background-image:url(),url(),url(),url();
```

**:: or ::**

```
<span class="foo"></span><span class="foo"></span><span class="foo"></span><span class="foo"></span>
```

Here is an idea of what the design is supposed to look like. Open to all suggestions, just trying to find the best/smartest/MOST RESPONSIVE way to do this.

Comment: Does it need to be a pure HTML/CSS solution?

Comment: also, do you want the arrangements of the animated items to be random/procedurally generated or just _look_ random?  if the latter, probably the easiest way is just to make an animated SVG where the SVG has all the stars or whatever you want to animate, in one file.  then that file just becomes your one background image.

Comment: @TNguyen It does not need to be pure HTML/CSS, you can use javascript. However they don't need to be random, they are actually part of the design and need to be positioned "roughly" around how they are in the image.

Comment: In that case, I would definitely suggest an animated SVG background.  It makes the front-end code more semantic and cleaner and SVG animation gives you more flexibility with regards to animation.  Plus, SVG for simple shapes like stars will be significantly smaller in filesize compared to GIF or PNG.

Comment: @TNguyen While I do understand what you are saying, I'm not sure if that actually answers my question. The question was about what approach would be taken to get the elements onto the page. Not if it should be an svg or not. I agree svg is a great way to go, but that's not actually answering my question. How would you put all of the svg's into position on the page that is different then what I have previously mentioned?

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but my solution is, create an animated SVG and then specify it as the background-image in your element.  That's how it "gets onto" your page.

Comment: Just to clarify, in case I wasn't clear before, I mean to create _one_ single SVG file that has all the individual animated elements together.  Then it just becomes one large image you can use as a background.  All your positioning and animation is done inside the SVG.

Comment: @TNguyen yeah, I hadn't followed your logic before. I thought you were talking about placing individual svg's onto the background. Thanks for clearing that up, it makes more sense now.

Comment: @TNguyen The other part of the equation, would be I have been given the icon already, and didn't want to push back onto my designers to "make it again" if I could avoid it.

Comment: Ok, well now you're talking more about how to work within a company rather than strictly a programming issue :) . I would say, if your new solution is superior, then make your case about why they should give you new assets.  Otherwise, do what I do when I don't have the patience to deal with others... do it yourself :) . Seriously, I have learned graphic design, animation, Photoshop, Illustrator... all sorts of skills simply because I couldn't be bothered to deal with uncooperative people.  It's really not that hard.

Comment: @TNguyen I don't know if I would go that extreme. It's the last day before break, and everyone is crunching before the holiday time off. I figured, there has to be someone out there whose encountered this before. Yes I can ask my peers for stuff, Yes I can certainly teach myself to create something in a design program. BUT.... sometimes someone better then you has a quick solution that takes just a second because they've done it before. That was my hope. That someone has coded something similar. I was also thinking maybe there was a javascript solution that I had not thought of yet.